# MS VS Fortran re-build and debug doesnt happen when I re-open the file

Tags: visual-studio-2013, fortran

After I write a program (Fortran) in MS Visual Studio, rebuild, and debug it. It shows me results. Once I close the file and after re-opening it doesn't allow me to re-build and debug it as those options seem to be disabled. Can anyone please help me troubleshoot this problem?

Comment: Welcome. Please take the Welcome [tour] and read [ask]. Which compiler do you use? Which exact steps you do so that we can try it ourselves?

Comment: Hello, I have figured out the problem by opening the .sln files. Thank you

Comment: However, I have another issue. I have multiple subroutines which I need to compile and run the final one which calls the previous. So I do like this:  ifort LU.f90 IDENTITY.f90 JACOBIAN.f90 BROY.f90 TR.f90 USER2.f90. This creates  .obj files of each of them. However it shows an unresolved Error 4  fatal error LNK1120: 3 unresolved externals Debug\USER2.exe. How to get rid of that and run the code and how? What should be the next steps.?

Comment: Do not put importsnt informatuon into comments. Rewrite your question or ask a new one. Do take the [tour] to see how to use this site.